# Is a PCB a requirement for an RFM95 family for HopeRF LoRa modules?

Tags: pcb, lora

I watched a few videos and read a couple of blogs regarding the HopeRF [RFM95W](http://www.hoperf.com/upload/rf/RFM95_96_97_98W.pdf) family of transceivers.

All of the videos recommend using a breakout PCB similar to [this one](https://pcbs.io/share/4Q1Z4) or this [other one](https://www.aliexpress.com/item/1pCS-LOT-ESP8266-serial-WIFI-module-adapter-plate-Applies-to-ESP-07-ESP-08-ESP-12E/32722296560.html), or this [one](http://cpham.perso.univ-pau.fr/LORA/resources/IMG_1672.JPG)

[One of the videos](https://youtu.be/HwAkhZXlg2c) states that the distance between the center of two IO holes on the RFM module is 2mm, and the distance of the top edge to the center of the first hole is 1mm, and thus standoffs are not an option.

I am curios what other options there might be?  Couldn't one just solder wires directly onto the module? If that is a bad idea, why?  If not a bad idea, what size wire would be best to use?

Please understand I have no real training in electronics and only self taught on YouTube.  My soldering skills are improving, and even with the PCB, soldering is required.  Just seems that the PCB is unnecessary in this case.  It is not a flat connect MCU.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The pitch is indeed 2mm (p120 in the datasheet you linked to).

Since RFM95W is not used alone you'd need to put other parts *somewhere*, so for permanent or repeatable solution it is better to make you own PCB and solder the module to it.

For experiments or one-off designs perfboard is cheap and convenient alternative to custom PCB, and breakouts like those basically work as pitch adapters.

And you are correct, PCB is not necessary. You can put everything in a box, or glue to the wall, or arrange in ikebana on a desk and connect with just about any wire that you can manage to solder. But in any case *some* soldering is required. Breakout boards like those *make soldering easier*, not harder.